# Firebase + react - db._checkNotDeleted is not a function как исправить

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-database

Не могу понять в чем проблема, не могу закинуть даже тестовые данные.

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "---",
  authDomain: "---",
  databaseURL: "---",
  projectId: "---",
  storageBucket: "---",
  messagingSenderId: "---",
  appId: "---"
}


// Initialize Firebase and Firebase Authentication
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const auth = getAuth(app)
export {auth}
```

ProfileEdit.js

```
import { useAuthValue } from './AuthContext'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getDatabase, ref, child, push, update,set } from "firebase/database";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import xtype from 'xtypejs'

import { auth } from './firebase'




function ProfileEdit() {
  const { currentUser } = useAuthValue();

  const db = ref(getDatabase());


  const [name, setName] = useState()
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState()
  const [payment, setPayment] = useState()
  const [address, setAddress] = useState()

  const Submit = () => {
      
     const postData = {
      address: "test",
      firstName: "test",
      paymentByCard: "test",
      phone: "test",
  
    };

    const data = {}
    data["users/" + currentUser?.uid] = postData
    console.log(data)
    return update(ref(db,data))
  }
  console.log(currentUser?.uid)



  return (


    <form action="" className="profile-filling" >
      <input type="text" name={"name"} id="" placeholder="Enter your  firstname" />
      <input type="text" name={"address"} id="" placeholder="Enter your  Address" />
      <input type="text" name={"phone"} id="" placeholder="Enter your  phoneNumber" />

      <div>
        <span>  Credit cart? </span>
        <input type="checkBox" name={"payment"} id="" placeholder="Enter your  firstname" />
        <span>Cahs?</span>
        <input type="checkBox" name={"payment"} id="" placeholder="Enter your  firstname" />
      </div>
      <span onClick={Submit}>Submit</span>
    </form>
  )
}

export default ProfileEdit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переделал по другому. Так же я обращался немного с ошибкой Users должно было начинаться с капса.

```
  const Submit = () => {
     const postData = {
      address: address,
      firstName: name,
      paymentByCard: payment,
      phone: phone,

    };

const data = {}
data["Users/" + currentUser?.uid] = postData
console.log(data)
update(ref(db), data)
```